# User Log-Ins at the same time

Tags: user-account

Can you tell me how many people can log in at the same time with one user name?  We are setting up video training in which multiple users will need to log in.

Comment: I recommend to **avoid sharing accounts between users**. Shared accounts make it harder to identify which user made changes to a contact, lead to lockouts if any one user changes their account, and will make it much harder for you to lock out a former staff member / volunteer down the track.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the video training is not what they are logging in to, but rather the CiviCRM system. There is no 'limit' but there will be server constraints. Depending on your server config, if you have 50 users and they all click on a complex query (such as an Include/Exclude Smart Group) then you may see smoke coming out of the screen ;-)

But fundamentally there is no limit to logged in users (which is a CMS issue rather than a CiviCRM issue anyway)